# Accessing a listview box

Tags: c#, winforms

I am pretty new to programming in c#. I have a listview `(ListViewProjects)` box in `ProjectListForm` but I want to be able to access the items in the `listview` box in `AddProjectForm`.  How can I access them? I was going to try to do something like this

```
ProjectListForm.ListViewProjects.Items.Clear
```

but when I type in `ProjectListForm., ListViewProjects` isn't an option.

Comment: You're using WinForms, I suppose?

Comment: inside ProjectListForm code you could try `this.ListViewProjects.Items.Clear()` you can only access static members with just classname as in `ProjectListForm.[AnyStaticPropertyOrMethod]`

Comment: Not enough information to gain an answer. I suggest reading up by getting a book (spot fixes will only get you so far). Does ProjectListForm save the projects someplace - e.g. a file ? In which case the OtherForm can read this file to gain access to the items. If not, then you would need to pass an object of the ProjectListForm to the OtherForm (as a ctor or method parameter) so that it can call `projectListFormInstance.ClearProjects();`

Comment: Yes, the user enters a project name in a textbox then it is put into a public static list<>, the list is saved to a file and also put into a listview box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set the list view's design time options to generate a public member (in control's properties, under Design set Modifiers to Public), or possibly better you could add a public property to `ProjectListForm` to expose either the list view or just the `Items` collection, eg:

```
public class ProjectListForm : Form
{
    ...
    public ListView.ListViewItemCollection ProjectsListViewItems
    {
        get { return ListViewProjects.Items; }
    }
}
```

The best way IMO is to write public methods in `ProjectListForm` that do what you're trying to achieve in `AddProjectForm`, such as `ProjectListForm.ClearProjects()`. That way you're not forcing `AddProjectForm` to depend on the implementation of `ProjectListForm`, say if you later want to change to a `TreeView`.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot achieve this way in C#. you need to create the instance of the object.

To do this you have to create the method in `ProjectListForm` and in that methos you have to call `this.ListViewProjects.Items.Clear`.

Now from the `AddProjectForm` you have to call this method of the running instance of `ProjectListForm`.

If you want to know more about how to make the call, then please give the flow about how do you show the AddProjectForm from the ProjectListForm.